# Select and Order a table with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am currently stuck with this problem.

I have a data matrix like this one but with a lot more of data:

[image]

I would like to sort this table by clicking in the sort button et create a new worksheet that make:

```
SELECT the two smallest values
FROM my table
ORDER BY Blue Column Name, Data_Value
```

Then the resoult would be:
[image]

Thank your for your help.

edit:
I have tried to order per column like this with the sort function but i is not the result i was expected at all:

```
'
' MySorting Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:E4").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C4"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D4"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1:E4"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:E4")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us some code you worked with?

Comment: Hi, here is my code, but it is not efficient at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your Sort filter won't be enough.

If you only want to use the sort function you need to have a 2 dimensional table:

```
 Paris France McDonald 100
 Paris France Wendy    120
 Paris France BK       10
 etc.
```

Then sorting will be easy.

If you want to do it like above in VBA, you need to copy your current table and make it a two dimensional table first. (like the example before.) When you finished that, you can use your sort.

But that's a lot of VBA for a task like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Indeed, i think i will be able to sort and order easily with excel. 
You mention that i will have to copy my current table and make it a two dimensional table. However, i can't really do this manually because i have a huge amount of data.
Thank you for your help again. Best regards